# react-native-mauron85-background geolocation error

Tags: react-native

The following error appears when try to build my react native for production  (running ./gradlew assembleRelease),

...

/node_modules/react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation/android/common/src/oreo/java/com/marianhello/bgloc/NotificationHelper.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
                  ^
  symbol:   class NotificationChannel
  location: package android.app

...

Execution failed for task ':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation-common:compileOreoReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Anybody encountered this error before?

Comment: Me to have this error. Any luck with you?

Comment: Didi you find any solution?

Comment: Do you have any example, I have got many link and sample there but could not found which method should I call and where

Answer (score 0):

Just adding what solved my problem in case anyone is having the same problem.

After tearing off a lot of hairs (although I lack it) I came to a solution. Not sure whether is gonna work for others, you can give it a try.

Add following codes in `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
}
```

And make sure the dependencies are installed.